# Apache camel file parsing issue with splitting and unicode character

Tags: unicode, apache-camel

All I need to do is read a .csv file and push the data in database. The issue I am facing is that the file may not follow the CSV format, example: """ (a single double quote within two double quotes), in which case apache camel throws out the entire file instead of that one record. In order to overcome that issue, I decided to split the file and unmarshal it line by line. In using that approach, now I am facing another issue where the unicode characters are not being preserved after tokenizing the body. Has anyone faced the same issue?
Here is my code snippet for the route:

from(file).split(body().tokenize("\r\n")).streaming().unmarshal(dataformat).end()

I tried few things to validate my theory that modifying the body is corrupting the unicode character. Following are the routes that I tried
1) from(file).to(file) -> Unicode character is preserved
2) from(file).split(body()).streaming().to(file) -> unicode character preserved
3) from(file).convertBodyto(String.class, "UTF-8").split(body()).streaming() -> Unicode character lost
4) from(file).split(body(String.clasS)).streaming().to(file) -> Unicode character lost.

I have also verified that my JVM is using UTF-8 for encoding and I also tried to set charset parameter in file component to UTF-8 but nothing changed.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

The unicode character, §, is getting converted to inverted ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your file has the UTF-8 encoding? You can always enforce the exchange encoding by

```
 <setProperty propertyName="Exchange.CHARSET_NAME">
      <constant>UTF-8</constant>
 </setProperty>
```

When working with files, I usually set the exchange encoding to what exactly the file is, then after reading it, changing the exchange encoding back to UTF-8.

Let me know if this helps.

R.

Comment: I changed my route to the following: from(file).setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME,constant("UTF-8")).convertBodyTo(String.class).split(body().tokenize("\r\n")).streaming().process().end  and the unicode character is still getting corrupted

Comment: That's why I think most likely your file isn't encoded in UTF-8. Have your tried other encodings such as iso-8859-1 ? Also debug it and see what the body look like when you change the exchange encoding.

Comment: "Zu¤iga" is what I see when using IS0-8859-1, "Zu�iga" when using UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for leading me in right direction. I ran file -I <filename> command on terminal and realized that the charset of the file I was trying to parse was us-ascii. I changed my property to us-ascii and the file parsed correctly; however, my route doesn't work as mentioned in my question. from(file).split(body().tokenize("\r\n")).streaming().unmarshal(dataformat).end()...It fails to process that unicode character and errors out. When converting the body to string using "us-ascii" it doesnt preserve the original symbod. I am back to square one :(

Comment: Ok that already sounds like improvement. Can you change the charset back to UTF-8 *after* it has read the file and before splitting?

Comment: I have my charset set to US-ASCII when reading the file. I have my route defined as from(file).setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME,constant("UTF-8")).convertBodyTo(String.class).split(body().tokenize("\r\n")).process.end() and it doesn't preserve the character. When removing the convertBodyTo() from the above route, the entire route fails when trying to parse the character. May be its just not possible to convert that character?

Comment: Hi Pri, is there any chance you could create a little unit test that reproduces this issue? I will personally fix it for you if you do that! Include a few lines of your csv in it that are problematic..

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a file that was generated in UNIX (through camel) but still had non-printable ASCII chars. This caused issues with the split which was using (streaming). I resorted to writing a simple custom splitter as I needed to stream the file (files were a few hundred MB in size).

```
from("direct:process").split().method(FileSplitter.class, 
"split(${body})").shareUnitOfWork().streaming()
```

It was easy to write the splitter. All i had to do was return a iterator that uses BufferedReader to return one-line at a time.